# `BGAppRefreshTask` vs `BGProcessingTask` understanding timing

Tags: ios, swift, background, background-task

I'm trying to understand the distinction between `BGAppRefreshTask` and `BGProcessingTask` where for processing Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtaskrequest?language=objc) say for a process that “takes minutes” whereas refresh [they say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgapprefreshtaskrequest?language=objc) for a “short request task.” I am iterating through workouts in HealthKit which takes under a minute, so should I be using BGAppRefreshTask?

Comment: FWIW there is some limited info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `BGAppRefreshTask` has a time limit of 30 seconds. So if you can't guarantee the task will take less than that time, the `BGProcessingTask` may probably more appropriate.

This was noted in the WWDC 2019 Session 707 Advances in App Background Execution. The relevant time index is: [18:51](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019-707/?time=1131)

Comment: In my experience BGProcessingTask may run for 5 minutes in iOS 13.5.1. After 295 seconds the expiration handler is fired.